# Shape a WCF service by endpoint

Tags: wcf, wsdl, wcf-endpoint

I have 2 contracts (cA & cB) implemented by a single WCF service with 2 endpoints (epA & epB).

This is **not** for security purposes, but purely for reasons of clarity/organization, I'd like to only "see" ContractA's operations when I discover the service via endpointA; and likewise, only see ContractB's operations via endpointB.

I don't need to "protect" these operations per se. The scenario is such that any given client only needs one "side" of the service, never both (but, the operations themselves share resources, so it makes sense to have a single service rather than 2 services).

It seems that any given service basically gets 1 WSDL, ergo all operations are exposed to all endpoints.  Is that the way it works, or is there a way to "shape" an endpoint by occluding operations not defined by the endpoints contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you're right - one service implementation class gets one WSDL which contains all service methods (from all service contracts) that this service class implements.

There are no ways present (as far as I know) to "shape" the WSDL in any (easy) way - WCF does offer ways to get into the process of creating the WSDL (statically or dynamically), but those aren't for the faint of heart. It would be much easier for you to just split the implementation of the service contracts into two separate classes and then you'd have two separate services, separate WSDL's and all.

Answer (score 1):

Marc is absolutelly right. I'm just adding why this happens in WCF. In WCF all metadata related functionality are based around service metadata behavior and mex endpoint. Both these features are defined on service level. So you can't take higher granuality (unless you write a lot of custom code) and specify metadata per endpoint.

WCF service (class) is directly mapped to wsdl:service element which exposes each contract as separate wsdl:port (in WCF known as endpoint). This is the main point in answering your question. If you don't want your second contract in that wsdl:service you can't implement it in the same class.

You have mentioned that your service contracts share resources. In that case your WCF service probably also contains business logic. That is a reason for your problems. The good design for implementing WCF services is to create them only as wrappers around separate business logic classes.

Comment: You're right my WCF operations perform business logic directly.  I hadn't considered implementing the service operations as wrappers to business classes but I realize now that would be a lot better in many ways, so thanks for this advice.